# Is there a way with Php to Pop the last element from an array and place it at the beginning?

Tags: php, arrays

I was wondering if it's possible with PHP to take the last element of an array and place that element at the beginning of the array.

When I Print my Array, it says something like this (I took away the whole urls):

```
Array ( 
    [0] => /bb-style.css 
    [1] => /bb-library.css 
    [2] => /bb-child.css 
    [3] => /bb-editor-style.css 
    [4] => /universal.css?cache=1584962088 
)
```

So is there a way to get that last one to the top? I would really appreciate it if someone can tell me the exact code needed, because I often interpret stuff wrong and still can't figure it out when I get an answer.

Comment: Have you made any attempts for yourself?

Answer (score 3):

Use [array_pop()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) with [array_unshift()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php)

```
<?php

    // Get and remove last
    $last = array_pop($array);

    // Insert at beginning
    array_unshift($arr , $last);
```

---

[Try it online!](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c0db5d0bd4610f7bd03e0458de32d397ec4953e8)

```
<?php

    $array = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
    $last = array_pop($array);
    array_unshift($array, $last);

    print_r($array);
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
)
```

Comment: `pop` .. need to remove it?

Answer (score 3):

```
$arr = array("one");
$arr[] = "two";
$arr[] = "three";

print_r($arr); // one, two, three


$last = array_pop($arr); // remove last item ("three")

array_unshift($arr, $last); // add removed item($last = "three") to the begining.

print_r($arr); // three, one, two
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it use array_pop() with array_splice() like following :

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);     
array_splice( $array, 0, 0,array_pop($array)); 
echo "<pre>";print_r($array);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
)
```